# Edit Javascript by loading/opening the page

Tags: php, javascript, dom

PHP's DOMDocument class allows you to load an html file, make changes to the elements, and then save it. This way we can change millions of webpages by just running a little script on every file there is. I want to know that is there a way to change the javascript code thats embedded on the page?

I developed an application that generates web pages, and I have been using it for months now. There are like 800 pages I have created so far. Now I have come to know that there was a small error in my javascript code and I want to correct it. The obvious solution is to open every single file and make the changes manually. Do I have any other chioce that is simple?

below is the javascript that is currently embedded on the page

```
var actNum='';
$.ajax({

       url:'DBOperations.php', 
       type: 'POST',
       async: 'false',
       data: {Command:'GET_ACTIVITY_NUMBER_DB', Title:'English/Level 1/Chapter 1/act 1'}, 
        success: function(value){   
                                    if(value)
                                    {
                                        actNum=value;
                                        document.getElementById('actNumDiv').appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
                                    }
                 }

       });
```

I want to send an extra variable "type" next to "Title" in the ajax call like this

```
 data: {Command:'GET_ACTIVITY_NUMBER_DB', Title:'English/Level 1/Chapter 1/act 1', type:'admin'}
```

Comment: is it the same javascript - why dont you move it into its own file?

Comment: Can you show us what you're trying to change? A `str_replace()` might work.

Comment: there are some variables that I set on page load which in turn gets different values for different webpages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use str_replace?

```
str_replace("data: {Command:'GET_ACTIVITY_NUMBER_DB',",
    "data: {Command:'GET_ACTIVITY_NUMBER_DB',type:'admin',",your_html_string);
```